# Physical interpretation of the spin connection field for the Dirac equation in curved spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, gauge-theory, dirac-equation, gauge-invariance, qft-in-curved-spacetime

When dealing with the Dirac equation in curved spacetime one has to replace the partial derivative with the following covariant derivative:

${\partial_{\mu}}-\frac{i}{4}\omega_{\mu}^{\alpha\beta}\sigma_{\alpha\beta}$

where $\omega_{\mu}^{\alpha\beta}$ is the spin connection. What type of physical field this spin connection corresponds to? In the case of the electroweak theory the gauge fields in the covariant derivative correspond to the weak gauge bosons but what actual physical field does the spin connection correspond to?

Comment: Simple and straightforward interpretation: $\sigma_{\alpha\beta}$ is the  generator of Lorentz group $SO(1,3)$, and spin connection $\omega_{\mu}^{\alpha\beta}$ is the corresponding gauge field. What else do you want to know?

Comment: My question was: what is the physical manifestation of this field? In other words, how is it observed and measured?

Comment: Then you are asking a different question. Please raise a new question for that.